# Change category name position in URL on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, seo, category-navigation

In Magento 1.9, I have installed Manadev seo extension. In that I need small  correction.

```
Current URL: https://domain.com/category-name/filter1/filter2/filter3.html

Expected URL: https://domain.com/filter3/filter2/filter1/cagegory-name.html.
```

Always category name should come in the last.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **Magento Admin** and enable **`Web Server Rewrites`**

> System → Configuration → General (Web) → Search Engines Optimization (Use Web Server Rewrites) → Set to YES

Comment: Already its enabled. Issue with changing the position of category-name to last.